# What does x (execute) permission do on unix sockets?

Tags: linux, permissions, unix-sockets

By my experience unprivileged user can not access unix socket he/she does not own without x bit set. What does this bit do exactly?

Comment: Is it the permission on the sockets or on the directory?

Comment: On a socket. Directory has mode 0755, so user can observe content. Socket has mode 0644, so logically user (which belongs to "others" because he/she does not own socket a belongs to group owning socket) should be able to write to the socket. But user gets permission deny message unless mode 0777 is applied to the socket.

Comment: @ВладимирТюхтин, `0644` means just read permission for the group members and "others", so only the owner would be able to access the socket (since the write permission controls it). `0666`, or just `0222` as read permission is not needed, would be enough to give access to everyone. But, rather than give permissions to everyone, I'd look into using groups to allow access.

Comment: I can confirm you do not need execute in order to connect to a socket. You do need write if you want to write to it.

Answer (score 15):

Nothing, as I can see.

The Linux [man page unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) says that the permissions of the directory containing a socket apply normally (i.e. you need `+x` on `/foo` to connect to `/foo/sock`, and `+w` on `/foo` to create `/foo/sock`) and that *write* permission controls connecting to the socket itself:

> On Linux, connecting to a stream socket object requires write permission on that socket; sending a datagram to a datagram socket likewise
>          requires write permission on that socket.

Apparently some other systems behave differently:

> POSIX does not make any
>          statement about the effect of the permissions on a socket file, and
>          on some systems (e.g., older BSDs), the socket permissions are
>          ignored.  Portable programs should not rely on this feature for security.

[`unix(4)` on FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=unix&apropos=0&sektion=4&manpath=FreeBSD%2012-current&arch=default&format=html) describes similar requirements. The Linux man page didn't say if socket access on some systems ignores the *directory* permissions too.

Removing the `x` bit from the socket seems to have the effect of giving a different error for trying execute the socket, but that's not much of a practical difference:

```
$ ls -l test.sock
srwxr-xr-x 1 user user 0 Jun 28 16:24 test.sock=
$ nc -U ./test.sock
Hello
$ ./test.sock
bash: ./test.sock: No such device or address
$ chmod a-x test.sock
$ nc -U ./test.sock
Hello
$ ./test.sock
bash: ./test.sock: Permission denied
```

(I did also test that indeed only the `w` bit seems to matter for accessing the socket on Debian's Linux 4.9.0.)

Perhaps the sockets you meant had all permission bits removed from the user, or you meant the `x` bit on the directory?

Comment: Why on Earth would you try to execute a socket?!

Comment: @AlexisWilke, because someone asked what the corresponding execute permission bit does on one.